# Why did the tutorial on Android Geofences dissapear?

Tags: android, android-geofence

This used to link to a great tutorial on how to get geofences up and running on Android called "Creating and Monitoring Geofences"

http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

I tried going back to look at the sample code today and its gone. I dug it up in the waybackmachine though:

http://web.archive.org/web/20131203150710/http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Is this document no longer up to date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Google Play services 6.5 highlights](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html):

> The `ActivityRecognitionClient`, **`LocationClient`**, and `PlusClient` classes are deprecated. If you used those APIs in your app and want to call Google Play services 6.5 or higher APIs, you must switch to the new programming model that utilizes [GoogleApiClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html). For more information about using [GoogleApiClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html), see [Accessing Google APIs](http://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html).
>
> Use these APIs instead of the deprecated APIs:
>   If you were previously using `LocationClient`, call the APIs in the [com.google.android.gms.location](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/package-summary.html) package instead.

In this case, you'd use the [GeofencingApi](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingApi.html) to access Geofences. Until the sample is updated to the new API, the tutorial was removed. Much of it still applies, but you'd need to substitute the new APIs where needed yourself.